# Maximum call stack size exceeded chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a learning extension for chrome with manifest v3. I need to find out the full URL of all requests sent by sites that contain a substring https://example . When trying to open the page, the console displays the message Maximum call stack size exceeded and displays console.error Unknown server error, msg=Maximum call stack size exceeded, requested_url=/webapi/spa/modules/error404. I need to track the URL in the content script

```
    function middlewareRequest(url, options) {
    if (url && url.includes && url.includes("https://example")) {
        console.log("URL:", url);
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(options.method || "GET", url, true);

        xhr.send(options.body || null);

        return xhr;
    } else {
        return window.fetch(url, options).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
    return middlewareRequest.apply(this, arguments);
};
window.fetch = function () {
    return middlewareRequest.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Apparently, there is a recursion somewhere, but apparently I don't understand the language well and don't see unnecessary function calls

Comment: You are reassigning globals then calling those globals

Comment: Oh yes, I just now noticed that I redefine window.fetch and call it inside the function, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, just need a new var to save original fetch method.

```
function middlewareRequest(url, options) {
if (url && url.includes && url.includes("https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail")) {
    console.log("URL:", url);
}

return originalFetch(url, options); // Call the original fetch function instead of window.fetch
}

const originalFetch = window.fetch; // Store the original fetch function

window.fetch = middlewareRequest; // Override window.fetch with the 
middlewareRequest function
```